# How to modify the offset position of y-axis values in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I want to shift my wave which i plotted to above the offset, for example offset value of my plot is -5000, then i want to shift my whole graph y axis to above -5000 thats means above my offset value.
does any one have any idea regarding this??

Comment: [ylim](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ylim.html)? Subtracting 5000 from the data? It is difficult to answer when you don't provide and context. Please post the code you use to generate the figure and the figure (i.e. you should post an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please read it.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes I had used the same idea for another plot

```
offset=(delta_rear_front_1 + 0.5*10^4);
y=delta_rear_front_1+offset;

a=plot(datastructs.SpringWayOut.mConfCircle_time,y,'red')
```

Thank anyway, actually I was complicating things and I got that and I had done it